# Posting files from applet to PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, applet

I have a few questions regarding uploading files to a HTTp request (from an applet). This is what I am following:
I am taking a screenshot of the screen using Applet's robot and storing the same on the local file system. The file I have saved on the local file system needs to be uploaded to Apache, eventually to be accessed by PHP.

```
public void sendBufferedImage(File file, BufferedImage screenImage, String urlPath) throws Exception
        {
             ImageIO.write(screenImage, "GIF", file); // This is to store the file in  
                                   a temp location on the local file system.
                 url = new URL(urlPath);
                 urlcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                 urlcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 urlcon.setDoOutput(true);
                 urlcon.connect();
                 out = new DataOutputStream(urlcon.getOutputStream());
                 out.write(file.getPath().getBytes());
         }
```

Does this complete writing the file to the HTTP request?

1. If so, how should reading the HTTP request work to get the file handle out of the byte array written to the HTTP request?
2. Can a file be written to the HTTP request only via byte array?
3. A sample of how the php code would look like while getting the file handle out of the HTTP request would help a great deal.

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry about the bad edit.. was already edited by the time I submitted the edit